# How do I mark text bold inside an already matched region in VIM syntax highlighting?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

Given something like:

> This is **\f** random text **\b** and more **\f*** and then some more.

- I want to make \f up until \f* grey
- I want the "tags" as bold (so they are grey but also become bold)

I can't get the priorities right so both the bolding and the colourisation occur.

```
syn match footnoteEnd /\\f\*/
syn match footnoteStart /\\f/
syn match footnoteBTag /\\f/
syn region footnoteInfo start=/\\f/ end=/\\f\*/

hi def footnoteInfo guifg=grey
hi def footnoteStart gui=bold
hi def footnoteBTag gui=bold
hi def footnoteEnd gui=bold
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
syn match footnoteDelimiter /\\f\*\?/ contained
syn match footnoteBTag /\\b/ contained
syn region footnoteInfo start=/\\f/ end=/\\f\*/ contains=footnoteDelimiter,footnoteBTag keepend

hi def footnoteInfo guifg=grey
hi def footnoteBTag gui=bold guifg=grey
hi def footnoteDelimiter gui=bold guifg=grey
```

Explanation:

- When Vim reaches the end of the region, it matches `footnoteStart` again before `footnoteEnd` and then `*` never gets bold. That's why I suggest using `footnoteDelimiter` instead.
- The `contained` argument was added to `footnoteDelimiter` and `footnoteBTag` because they occur into a region.
- `contains=footnoteDelimiter,footnoteBTag` specifies which syntax groups are allowed into the region.
- `keepend` makes the matching of an end pattern of the outer region also end any contained item.